# Linking metro css and jade

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug, metro-ui-css

I have a html code in jade but i find it difficult to understand how the body property is set from jade in css. I couldnt see any body tag in the css file.

My html(jade)

```
html
 head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/control/css/metro-bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/control/css/vcca.css')
    script(src="/control/js/jquery.min.js")

    // script(src='/control/js/metro.min.js')
    // script(src='/control/js/metro/metro-progressbar.js')
    //script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    //script.

    //var socket = io.connect(document.domain+':3000'); //'+port);
    script(src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js")
    script(src="/control/script.js")
    // script(src="/js/metro/metro-*.js")
 body.metro.vcca
    div.tile-area.tile-area-dark.text-center
        div.container
            h2.font1.fg-white Visualisation Centre
            br
            h3.font2.fg-white Please enter the 5 digit PIN
            input.font2.text-center.pininput(type='password')#pinInput
            div.container#numPad
```

What does **body.metro.vcca** refer to?
Where should i look for in the css files to know the property of the body tag? I needed to change the background color of the body. How can i do that?
 What does  h2.font1.fg-white means? where do i find it?

Thankks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Run your app, open it in the browser and bring up the developer tools on your browser (normally with F12 on most of the browsers) go to HTML or element tab and navigate select the body (as shown below):

[image: Developer Tools Screenshot]

As you see in the right panel, there is a list of all tag/class/ids with their pertinent styles. So you need to look for body.metro or .metro to find it's styles. and once you find it it you can see it's file name (written in blue color to the right side) and its line number, if you click on it, goes directly to that bit of css code.

If you're using chrome it would be like this :
[image: Chrome Developer tools]